How to get Dependabot to run test suite in GitHub Actions?
I have configured Dependabot in GitHub Actions. However, Dependabot cannot access repo secrets, so Dependabot PRs fail tests because GitHub Action's secrets aren't accessible.
https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/3253#issuecomment-797125425 suggests using pull_request_target, but the issue with that is, I believe the tests job won't pull in the newer dependencies as posed by Dependabot.
I also don't want to duplicate tens of secrets over to Dependabot's specific secrets as detailed here.
How can I get Dependabot initiated PRs to:

Run the tests job with newer dependencies specified by Dependabot
Without re-specifying secrets to Dependabot

